# How to loop through all the files queued and upload 1 file at a time using Dropzone

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, stream, dropzone.js

I am using [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to upload files into my [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) app.
Dropzone documentation suggests using this [multiple-uploads](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-uploadMultiple) script:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token()}}'},
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 999, // MB
    uploadMultiple: true,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    url: "{{ url('/upload') }}",
    parallelUploads: 1
 };
```

And in the Laravel App I have to stream the uploaded files to my `CLOUD/LOCATION`.

```
public function upload() {
    ...
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $file->move(public_path('tmp'), $name);
        $stream = fopen(public_path('tmp') . '/' . $name, 'r+');
        if (Flysystem::writeStream("MY/CLOUD/LOCATION/.$name, $stream)) {
            File::cleanDirectory(public_path('tmp'));
            fclose($stream);
            return "success";
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

What I see happening is that Dropzone uploads all the files to Laravel, then Laravel starts looping through the files, and uploading them to `CLOUD/LOCATION`. Meanwhile (if the size is large enough) the client gets a `time-out`.

Can I force Dropzone to loop through files 1-by-1 and `POST` them individually, or is there a better way that I'm missing?

Comment: Can't you just set the [maxFilesize](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-maxFilesize) option?

Comment: @Adrenaxus I don't see how that would answer my question. Also the `maxFilesize : 999` is set.

Comment: Well, if you set `maxFilesize` dropzone won't try to upload the image in the first place if it is too big. The user just gets notified that the image he choose is too big. But maybe I did not understand your problem correctly...

Comment: @Adrenaxus I actually want to allow the user to upload large files. I just want to upload/process them 1-by-1, not all at once. Let's say he uploads 50 files, 10Mb/each ... Then he has to wait while the application processes 500Mb of content till the controller responds, but if it was 1-by-1 then the client would get a response every 10Mb